# React-bootstrap Carousel infinte loop?

Tags: reactjs, image, loops, carousel, sliding

I use the `react-bootstrap` **carousel** in my [react](/questions/tagged/react) project.

The last image slides back to the first one from left to right.

The expected action would be that it resumes the sliding from right to left.

There is no explicit "infinite loop" option.

Does anybody encounter this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In index.js, my App component was wrapped in the <React.StrictMode>. When I removed it, the carousel works like it should!